# align text baseline over hr

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to align the text just above the hr tag like the logout button using bootstrap.
Here's what I want to achieve:

[image: text to bottom]

bootstrap code :

```
        <div className="position-relative">
            <hr/>
            <div className="position-absolute end-0 bottom-0 d-flex">
              <p className="align-baseline //not working">Logged in as {user?.email}</p>
              <button onClick={handleLogout} className="btn btn-primary ms-2 m-1">Logout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Glad for any help

#Edit :
after adding mb-0 to my p tag :
[image: not working either]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the image, your `<p>` has some `margin-bottom`, add the bootstrap class `mb-0` to the `<p>` tag.

Then to align the `<p>` to the bottom, you'd need to have the flex content pushed to bottom, that will be done with adding `align-items-end` to the `div`.

I also added a small padding to stop it from sticking to the bottom.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/omser28d/4/)

Edit: As per the answer from G-Cyrillus, you actually don't need the positions either (I overlooked it before). A little change in structure and whole thing looks the same with lesser code. [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/omser28d/7/)

Comment: I tried it , butstill stays on top

Comment: Updated the answer with a fiddle, works now.

Answer (score 0):

Here both `<p>` and `<button>` are part of d-flex. You can align both the items by using  `align-items` utilities on flexbox containers to change the alignment of flex items on the cross axis (the y-axis to start, x-axis if flex-direction: column).

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">...</div>
```

You can find more resource here [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#align-items).

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need absolute position , flex & order can do .

example

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column"><!-- make it a flex column to use order -->
      <hr class="order-2 m-0" /><!-- resets margin & order -->
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end"><!-- here use the justify-content-xx class you need -->
        <p class="m-0 mt-auto">Logged in as <b>SO User</b></p><!-- reset margins-->
        <button onClick={handleLogout} class="btn btn-primary ms-2 m-1">Logout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```